# Setting the CampaignMember "Status" field in Apex

Tags: apex, campaign-member

There seems to be a hole in my head today. I can't programmatically (in a test class in this case) set the "Status" field in a CampaignMember object.

Long and short is, I insert this in my test method:

```
new CampaignMember(CampaignId=testCampaign.Id, ContactId=contacts.get(i).Id, Status='Accepted')
```

but when I run the test, if I debug the CampaignMember object, I get this:

```
CampaignMember:{CampaignId=70124000000Hr3qAAC, Status=Sent, Id=00v24000000RxBmAAK, ContactId=00324000001p7w6AAA}
```

As you can see, status is remaining at the default "Sent"

I have read the docs

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm

and noted some blogs that talk about how you have to set the "Text" value of the status (despite the fact it's a complicated picklist in the background).

There is an "Accepted" value in the Customise > Campaign > CampaignMember > Fields > Status configuration. I just don't seem to be able to make it stick? Anyone have any advice/input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create `CampaignMemberStatus` objects for your Campaign before you can assign them to `CampaignMember` objects for that Campaign.

Once you've done that your status changes should stick.

```
CampaignMemberStatus newStatus = new CampaignMemberStatus(
    CampaignID=campaign.id,
    Label='New',
    IsDefault=false,
    HasResponded=false,
    SortOrder=3
);

insert newStatus;
```

Ensure that your `SortOrder` is 3 or greater since 1 and 2 are taken up by the default 'Sent' and 'Responded' status values.

You will need to repeat this for every Campaign that you want this status for, this mimics using 'Advanced Setup' to set the statuses for a Campaign in the UI.

Comment: I do already have a CampaignMemberStatus object for "Assigned" - do I (or can I) just "apply" that one to my new test Campaign or do I have to create a new one like this each time?

Comment: New ones need to be created each time, this mimics using 'Advanced Setup' to set the statuses for a Campaign in the UI.

Comment: That has worked perfectly.