# Can't access campaign members on campaign controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller

I have this portion of code in my test class:

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign(Name='prova1' , isActive=TRUE);
    insert campaign;
    System.debug('Campaign id: ' + campaign.Id);

    Lead lead = new Lead(Company='Company1', Status='Open', LastName='gj', Email='sgj1234@gmail.com');
    insert lead;
    System.debug('Lead id: ' + lead.Id);

    CampaignMember cm1 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=campaign.Id, Status='DS', LeadId=lead.Id);
    insert cm1;
    System.debug('CampMember id: '+cm1.Id);

    ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(campaign);
    HandlerGC hgc = new HandlerGC(controller);

    hgc.ccgCampagne();
```

The ccgCapagne method in the HandlerGC class contains:

```
public HandlerGC(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    IdCampaign = (String)controller.getRecord().Id;
    ShowMessage =false;
    //Text = 'wanna proceed';
}

public PageReference ccgCampagne(){

    AllMember = [Select Id, CampaignId, LeadId, ContactId, Status from CampaignMember where CampaignId = :IdCampaign and Status = 'DS'];
    System.debug('A' + IdCampaign);
    List<Case> AllCase = new List<Case>();
    AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();

    AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

    Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;

    system.debug('Member List'+AllMember);
    if(AllMember.size()>0){

        system.debug('IF');

        for(CampaignMember CM: AllMember){
etc .......
```

Now the coverage of the code only gets until the 
if(AllMember.size()>0) part of the code, wich it should pass without problem since there is/should be one campaign member, but there seems to be none.

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure the CampaignMember is getting inserted ? What is the debug log telling about : `System.debug('CampMember id: '+cm1.Id);` from the test class ?

Comment: Yes, it gives a valid SFDC id in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the problem. The campaignMember's status was automatically changed to 'Sent' after the insertion.
As far as I understood a campaign, by default, doesn't allow you to use the custom values that you have added to the picklist.
If you want a campaign to have campaignMembers with a custom value of status(even values which you have already created) you first have to go to Advanced setup in the campaign page and add the already made values that can be used for its campaignMembers.

Translated to apex going to the advanced setup and doing this would mean creating a CampaignMemberStatus Object first, giving it your campaign's id and inserting it.

so, before inserting the CampaignMember cm1 with status 'DS', i should first do the following:

```
CampaignMemberStatus dsStatus = new CampaignMemberStatus(
    CampaignID=campaign.id,
    Label='DS',
    IsDefault=false,
    HasResponded=false,
    SortOrder=3
);

insert dsStatus;
```

Thanks for contributing to the solution @crmprogdev
References taken from this post: [Setting the campaignmember status field in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59750/setting-the-campaignmember-status-field-in-apex)

Comment: Good find. Have bookmarked this for later.

Answer (score 2):

Using code like below where you use an object's name as a variable is not a good idea and can often be problematic:

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign(Name='prova1' , isActive=TRUE);

Lead lead = new Lead(Company='Company1', Status='Open', LastName='gj', Email='sgj1234@gmail.com');
```

I would recommend you change the above to something like below:

```
Campaign campgn = new Campaign(Name='prova1' , isActive=TRUE);

insert campgn;
System.debug('Campaign id: ' + campgn.Id);

Lead l = new Lead(Company='Company1', Status='Open', LastName='gj', Email='sgj1234@gmail.com');

insert l;
System.debug('Lead id: ' + l.Id);

CampaignMember cm1 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=campgn.Id, Status='DS', LeadId=l.Id);

insert cm1;
System.debug('CampMember id: '+cm1.Id);

ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(campgn);

HandlerGC hgc = new HandlerGC(controller);

hgc.ccgCampagne();
```

...and see if that doesn't resolve your issue.

**Edit**

Since the above didn't solve your problem, there was something that had bothered me about your code that I didn't address at the time I posted this - in part because you didn't include all of your code.

It appears that you're creating a `Case` from your list. It doesn't appear as though you've created a `Contact` with a related `Account` that you've added to this `Campaign`. Normally, a `Case` requires a `Contact` with a related `Account`. Without a contact, I'm not certain how you can create the Case.

So, I suggest you add debug statements to your handler code as shown below. I have also added some additional comments on your code that may or may not be relevant as you may have implemented them elsewhere.

```
AllMember = [Select Id, CampaignId, LeadId, ContactId, Status from CampaignMember where CampaignId = :IdCampaign and Status = 'DS'];

System.debug('A' + IdCampaign);
System.debug('AllMember LeadId = ' + AllMember.LeadId);
System.debug('AllMember CampaignId = ' + AllMember.CampaignId);
// System.debug('AllMember ContactId = ' + AllMember.ContactId);
// If you don't have a ContactId the above line will throw a null pointer exception 
System.debug('AllMember Status = ' + AllMember.Status);

List<Case> AllCase = new List<Case>();
// I don't see where the Case gets inserted in your method, so don't follow your code from here

AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
// I don't see where the AssignmentRule gets inserted in your method

AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];
```

Comment: i understand, very good point since apex is case-insensitive but that was not the problem

Comment: The Assignment Rule is applied to the DMLOptions instance called dmlOpts, and then in another part of the code i do myCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);

About the Case creation,
i think it can create one either with a lead id or a case id, not both are needed as far as i can see, i can create a Case with a Lead Id

Comment: Edit: i meant either with a lead Id or a contact* id