# Testing CampaignMember.HasResponded

Tags: apex, unit-test, campaign, campaign-member

I am trying to test a trigger that requires CampaignMember.HasResponded to be true.

I am having a problem creating a CampaignMember with a HasResponded status of true through apex.

This is similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59750/setting-the-campaignmember-status-field-in-apex), but it doesn't directly address the HasResponded issue. I originally tried CampaignMember.HasResponded editing it directly, but the field doesn't allow direct updates.

I have tried both through creating custom CampaignMemberStatus and also by using the default ('Sent' and 'Responded'). The Status on the CampaignMember is updated to the string, but the HasResponded field doesn't update.

Any ideas?

```
    //Campaigns
    Campaign c1 = new Campaign(Name = 'CampaignTest1');
    insert c1;

    CampaignMemberStatus cms11 = new CampaignMemberStatus(
        CampaignId = c1.Id,
        Label = 'Positive',
        SortOrder = 4,
        IsDefault=false,
        HasResponded=true
    );
    CampaignMemberStatus cms12 = new CampaignMemberStatus(
        CampaignId = c1.Id,
        Label = 'Negative',
        SortOrder = 3,
        IsDefault=true,
        HasResponded=false
    );


    insert cms11;
    insert cms12;


    //Campaign Members (Contacts are just generic filler contacts created earlier)
    CampaignMember cm11 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=c1.Id, ContactId=ct1.Id, Status = 'Positive');
    CampaignMember cm12 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=c1.Id, ContactId=ct2.Id, Status = 'Negative');
    CampaignMember cm13 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=c1.Id, ContactId=ct3.Id, Status = 'Sent');
    CampaignMember cm14 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId=c1.Id, ContactId=ct4.Id, Status = 'Responded');


    insert cm11;
    insert cm12;
    insert cm13;
    insert cm14;


    System.debug([SELECT Label, HasResponded FROM CampaignMemberStatus WHERE CampaignId = :c1.Id]); //The custom Campaigns are listed (not the default ones though)
    System.debug(cm11.Status+' '+cm11.HasResponded); // Should be 'Positive true' but it gives me 'Positive false'
    System.debug(cm12.Status+' '+cm12.HasResponded); // 'Negative false'
    System.debug(cm13.Status+' '+cm13.HasResponded); // 'Sent false'
    System.debug(cm14.Status+' '+cm14.HasResponded); // Should be 'Responded true' but it gives me 'Responded false'
```

Comment: did you try test.loadData?

Comment: actually - my above comment was stupid (system audit fields on my mind) - `hasResponded` is set automatically by SFDC when the CM is DMLd and has a CMS predefined as responded (or not) - covered nicely in the doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm. @sfdcfox pegged it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't query the individual rows back from the database. Simple mistake, really, but catching it is a bit harder. This behavior occurs because the variables cm11, etc are memory representations that are independent of the database; the DML operation will only ever return an Id value for you, so if you want any additional fields, you have to query them back from the database. You'll want to do this (after inserting your members):

```
cm11 = [SELECT HasResponded, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = :cm11.Id];
cm12 = [SELECT HasResponded, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = :cm12.Id];
cm13 = [SELECT HasResponded, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = :cm13.Id];
cm14 = [SELECT HasResponded, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = :cm14.Id];
```

Or, even better, put them into a map:

```
Map<Id, CampaignMember> members = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>([SELECT HasResponded, ContactId, CampaignId, Status FROM CampaignMember]);
```

Then, check *those* values:

```
System.debug(cm11.Status+' '+members.get(cm11.Id).HasResponded); // Should be 'Positive true'
System.debug(cm12.Status+' '+members.get(cm12.Id).HasResponded); // 'Negative false'
System.debug(cm13.Status+' '+members.get(cm13.Id).HasResponded); // 'Sent false'
System.debug(cm14.Status+' '+members.get(cm14.Id).HasResponded); // Should be 'Responded true'
```